# Проблема с запросом SQL

Tags: mysql

Ошибка:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\localhost\www\phpblog\view_cat.php on line 64
```

Код:

```
$result77 = mysql_query("SELECT stroka FROM option", $db);
$myrow77 = mysql_fetch_array($result77);
$num = $myrow77["stroka"];
// Извлекаем из URL текущую страницу
@$page = $_GET['page'];
// Определяем общее число сообщений в базе данных
$result00 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE cat='$cat'");
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($result00);
$posts = $temp[0];
// Находим общее число страниц
$total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
$total =  intval($total);
// Определяем начало сообщений для текущей страницы
$page = intval($page);
// Если значение $page меньше единицы или отрицательно
// переходим на первую страницу
// А если слишком большое, то переходим на последнюю
if(empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
  if($page > $total) $page = $total;
// Вычисляем начиная с какого номера
// следует выводить сообщения
$start = $page * $num - $num;
// Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,description,date,author,mini_img,view FROM data WHERE cat='$cat' ORDER BY id LIMIT $start, $num",$db);
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема.  Подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: а что находится в строке 64?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте такой запрос (замените двумя строчками), а если $cat число просто уберите апострофы в вашем запросе:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE cat='%s'",    mysql_real_escape_string($cat));  
$result00 = mysql_query($query);
```